# Create form which doesn't leave the page and modifies CSS upon submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I want to create a form which sends me an email, but also doesn't load a new page, but instead simply modifies some CSS values on that same page.

I've been searching this site and have been playing with some code. I've tried to do this via JavaScript (validation), PHP (process and format email), and jQuery (send email and modify CSS), but it just isn't quite right. I'm fairly new to these languages, so it is a bit difficult.

Currently, it correctly validates the form via JavaScript, and doesn't submit unless it validates. Perfect. It also sends the email which is great! The problem is it loads my PHP page rather than staying on the current page. The echo "Thank you..." gets placed on the PHP page not in the div in my HTML via jQuery. Also, I'm confused by the PHP and jQuery code. The PHP currently sends the email, but jQuery is supposed to do that instead. But if I delete it from the PHP, it doesn't send the email.

If you could help me put all these pieces together I'd surely appreciate it!

HTML form:

```
                <form id='form' method='post' onsubmit="return validateForm()" action='sendemail.php'>
                    Name: <br />
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
                    <br />
                    Email: <br />
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
                    <br /><br />
                    Subject: <br />
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
                    <br />

                    Comments:</a> <br />
                    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
                    <br />

                    <input type="image" src="..." alt="Submit" name="myFormSubmitted" value="Submit" />        
                </form>
                <div id="formResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
```

JavaScript (validation):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                var validName = false;
                var validEmail = false;
                var validSubject = false;
                var validComments = false;

                //Perform validation here...

if (validName && validEmail && validSubject && validComments) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

PHP sendemail.php (process form, format email):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['myFormSubmitted'])) {
//Construct format here.....
// Blank message to start with so we can append to it.
    $message = '';

    // Construct the message
    $message .= <<<TEXT
        Name: {$_POST['name']}
        Email: {$_POST['email']}
        Subject: {$_POST['subject']}
        Comments: {$_POST['comments']}  
        {$checkString}
TEXT;
$to = 'sendToThisEmail@example.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$from = $_POST['name'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['email'];

    $header = 'From: ' . $from . '<' . $fromEmail . '>';

    //Send the email - shouldn't be here!
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    echo 'Thank you for your Email. We will get in touch with you very soon.';
}
?>
```

jQuery (send email, modify CSS):

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $.post('sendemail.php', {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), comments: $('#comments').val(), myFormSubmitted: 'yes'}, function(data) { //I don't understand this line
        $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100'); //Place echo in original page
        //Add more CSS changes here...
        $('#name, #email, #comments').val(''); // Clear the inputs - what does this do?
    }, 'text');
    return false;
});
            }
```

Comment: Am I the only one here who understands the question, and doesn't just try to fix the asker's code assuming it's broken?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the form from actually posting and taking you to the PHP page, you need to do a `preventDefault()` in your jQuery `submit()` function like this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm) {
        $.post(
            'sendemail.php',
            {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(),
                myFormSubmitted: 'yes'
            },
            function(data) { //I don't understand this line
                $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100'); //Place echo in original page
                //Add more CSS changes here...
                $('#name, #email, #comments').val(''); // Clear the inputs - what does this do?
            },
            'text'
         );
     } else {
         // form is not validated, perhaps do something to notify user here
     }
}
```

Note I have also added the form validation with this onsubmit function.  This will allow you to remove the onsubmit property from the `<form>` element.

This should allow everything else to work.

Comment: This won't work because of the `onsubmit` attribute in his HTML form which will receive a boolean true from validateForm if the form is valid.

Comment: Note the last paragraph of the question: "If you could help me put all these pieces together I'd surely appreciate it!".

Comment: @BenjaminPaap Yes indded didn't notice that on his his HTML.  I have revised my answer to include the form validation within the submit function.

Answer (score 1):

Your form gets submitted because you have a `onsubmit` attribute which calls `validateForm()`.  validateForm() returns true if everything is valid. You should remove that attribute and call the function in you jQuery `submit` EventHandler and prevent the event from bubbling.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    if (validateForm()) {
        $.post(
            'sendemail.php', 
            {
                name: $('#name').val(), 
                email: $('#email').val(), 
                comments: $('#comments').val(), 
                myFormSubmitted: 'yes'
            }, 
            function(data) {
                $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100');
                $('#name, #email, #comments').val(''); /* Clear the inputs */
            }, 
            'text'
        );
    }

    // LINES ADDED
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false` alone should have the same effect.

Comment: you are right but his error is in his validateForm function. It will return true if its valid.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML form. There is a `onsubmit` attribute which will get a boolean true back from validateForm if the form is valid. So the form will be submitted before his EventHandler will be called.

Comment: Edited my answer 8 mins ago. Read it again please. ;-)

Comment: Note the last paragraph of the question: "If you could help me put all these pieces together I'd surely appreciate it!".

Comment: Thank you for the responses guys! I've implemented this code, and removed the onsubmit from my form. Now when I click submit it doesn't validate it, it loads the PHP page which states the echo text, but it doesn't actually send the email. :/

Comment: I can confirm I have jQuery linked correctly, but it looks like it isn't calling the jQuery function. But it is now sending the email (via the PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a form with a submit, bind your "submit" button to send an Ajax call out to your PHP.  Your PHP would do what it needs to, and return control and any data back to your javascript, which can take any additional action in response to that data.

Google "Ajax".  It's the key to making all this work.

Comment: Not if he's submitting a form.  He needs to extend his Ajax use so he replaces his form submission.  If he is using Ajax, he is not transferring page control, which his question said he did.

Comment: Note the last paragraph of the question: "If you could help me put all these pieces together I'd surely appreciate it!".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an asynchronous ajax call to the php script. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for specific details, but here is snippet that you can use (with some modifications of course)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sendemail.php",
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
        $(this).addClass("someclass");
    }
});
```

Comment: Note the last paragraph of the question: "If you could help me put all these pieces together I'd surely appreciate it!".

Answer (score 0):

To join the pieces together:

Add the jQuery library to the head, before the scripts that use it, as `<script src="...">`

Add the `jQuery` part as a script somewhere in the document. The `<head>` is the best place for this. Holding the code in an external document also helps.

If the script is included before the form, wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`. If it's not then you can do it anyways to prevent future bugs.

Add the `Javascript` part as a script, most likely to the same `script` tag as the `jQuery` part.

Remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the form, since now the `submit` handler will be calling `validateForm`.

`this` within the submit handler refers to the form being submitted. You can use this to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in that way:

If you create a form the submit will only be submitted to the server, if it is submitted. This will reload your page.

One solution is to submit the form into a named iframe.

```
<iframe height="1px" width="1px" name="hiddenSubmit" src="" />
<form id='form' method='post' onsubmit="return validateForm()" action='sendemail.php' target='hiddenSubmit'>[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a answer for this question  in another forum:

It involves no JS.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        print "<div class=\"h1span\">Thank you!</div>\n";
    }
    ?>
```